# PHP Using ($_GET['url']) and then displaying that json data?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php

function get_stuff()
{
    ($_GET['http://****RemovedForSecurityPurposes****.repairshopr.com/api/v1/tickets?api_key=****RemovedForSecurityPurposes****']);
    echo $_GET;
}

get_stuff();

?> /* Yes, Pointless closing tag, I'm cool like that. */
```

For some reason when I run this code the output I'm getting is "Array" and I can't figure out why? I know it is an array that I'm getting from the URL but I thought it would just print in whatever format its in? Am I missing something?

Thanks In advance!

Comment: your code makes no sesee, $_GET is a super global, not a function for "getting" some remote site

Comment: to get the contents of a remote site, you need to use, CURL, or file_get_contents(), or fopen(). That list is ordered by best option.

Answer (score 0):

> The Message of OP *when I run this code the output I'm getting is
>   "Array"*.

You need to use `file_get_contents` to read a file from a remote server. If your file response an array then you have to use `print_r` or `var_export` or `var_dump`. Or if your file response is a string(json) then you need to store it in a variable and apply a decode method.

```
function get_stuff(){
    $response = file_get_contents('http://****RemovedForSecurityPurposes****.repairshopr.com/api/v1/tickets?api_key=****RemovedForSecurityPurposes****');
    print_r($response); // if array
    $arr = json_decode($response); // decode of json
    print_r($arr);
}

get_stuff();
```

I think you will understand what i mean. Let me know if you are useful or need some help.

Comment: don't you think putting print_r() will also print empty array?

Comment: noooooo: http://ideone.com/Je9KrN How can you have 5k rep and this this is anything near right

Comment: so? this still gets nothing from the the remote api.

Comment: I really don't think you understand the question

Comment: Yes, I think so. Okey remove all comments, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass website URL to [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

You should use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://YOUR_URL');
```

If you have valid json then you can convert it to an array.

```
$data = json_decode($content, true);
```

then print it,

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
```